# Update multiple table rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Im currently quite new to javascript and im just trying to learn some basic things. Im not so bad in other languages so i do understand concepts etc.

I have a table with 10 rows for example, One of the cells is a "CaseID" and it exists for every row. Im trying to use the Math.Random property to generate random numbers.

My problem i hit first was i was using the ID property in my HTML and obviously this is unique, next i used class. I tried to append the output with an index but this again only worked for the first cell and nothing for the rest.

**HTML:**

```
<td class="caseID"></td>
```

**JS:**

```
var caseID = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000));
document.getElementsByClassName("caseID")[0].innerHTML = caseID;
```

This all works great for the first cell/row but every other row returns blank. Im assuming because i need to perhaps create an array/indexing but im unsure on how to do this.

Could i create a variable:

```
var tds = document.getelementsbyclassname("caseID");
```

And maybe write a foreach etc? again not sure on how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes you can apply forEach to a nodelist like this `[].forEach(tds, function...)`

Comment: It works fine because you apply it only to the first selected element (`[0]`). You need to apply it to all other elements as well. Look up "How to iterate elements returned by getElementsByClassName"

Comment: Thank you cool people of the world, ive managed to get it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a foreach like this, which would be a lighter syntax

```
document.getElementsByClassName("caseID").forEach(function(element) {
    var caseID = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000));
    element.innerHTML = caseID;
})
```

You can use a good old for loop, use a more "separate the steps" way which could help you understand more how javascript works. I will use `querySelectorAll` but you can do it with `getElementsByClassName`

```
var myTds = document.querySelectorAll('caseID');
// You don't want to calculate the length at each loop
for (var i = 0, length = myTds.length; i < length; i++) {
    var caseID = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000));
    var element = myTds[i];
    element.innerHTML = caseID;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Note that both `QuerySelectorAll` and `GetElementsBy...` methods will return iterables so you can loop over it

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByClassName("caseID");

if ( tds.length ) { // just a check to make sure you've found somethiung
    var caseID = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000));

    for(i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        tds[i].innerHTML = caseID;

        caseID = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, managed to get it working exactly how i wanted.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by write a foreach for class element in javascript.

```
var cases_list = document.querySelectorAll('.caseID');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(cases_list, function(elements, index) {
    // conditional here.. access elements
});
```

OR if you use jquery than you can do this by

```
$('.caseID').each(function(index, obj){
   //you can use this to access the current item
});
```

Comment: the `querySelectorAll` just uses a simple string argument, the dot is not good there

Comment: @zendling  the  `querySelectorAll`  use a selector to select. so if we need to select class elements we have to pass selector. for reference you can read here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll  thank you.

Comment: darn, I was hasty with my response, you are 100% right; I'm sorry